# Android - Compose - Create a Custom shape

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, shapes

I've been trying to make this shape in compose

[image]

I feel like I'm pretty close to it but I can't find a way to make the rounded shape at the bottom.
I tried using the bezier curve with `cubicTo` but I can't make it work.
Any help would be very appreciated,
Thanks in advance ! :D

Here's the code

```
    class PromptShape(
    private val shapeData: PromptShapeData,
) : Shape {
    override fun createOutline(
        size: Size,
        layoutDirection: LayoutDirection,
        density: Density
    ): Outline =
        Outline.Generic(
            Path().apply {
                val indentShapeData = IndentShapeData(height = -7f)
                val arrowHeight = 14f
                val arrowWidth = 34f
                val cornerShape = size.minDimension * (50 / 100f)
                val capsuleHeight = size.height - arrowHeight
                reset()
                moveTo(cornerShape, 0f)

                lineTo(size.width - cornerShape, 0f)

                // Top Right Angle
                arcTo(
                    rect = Rect(
                        offset = Offset(size.width - cornerShape, 0f),
                        size = Size(cornerShape, cornerShape)
                    ),
                    startAngleDegrees = 270f,
                    sweepAngleDegrees = 90f,
                    forceMoveTo = false
                )

                // 6. Bottom Right Corner
                arcTo(
                    rect = Rect(
                        offset = Offset(size.width - cornerShape, capsuleHeight - cornerShape),
                        size = Size(cornerShape, cornerShape)
                    ),
                    startAngleDegrees = 0f,
                    sweepAngleDegrees = 90f,
                    forceMoveTo = false
                )

                // 7. Bottom line from Right to Left
                lineTo(size.width - cornerShape, capsuleHeight)

                val arrowHalfWidth = arrowWidth / 2

                val rightArrow = (size.width / 2 - arrowHalfWidth)
                // 5. Bottom Line Center -> Left.
                lineTo(rightArrow, capsuleHeight)

//                cubicTo(71f, 34f, 87f, 0f, startX, size.height)
//                cubicTo(
//                    23f, 0f,
//                    39f, 34f,
//                    (size.width / 2 - arrowWidth), size.height
//                )

                lineTo(size.width - cornerShape, capsuleHeight)

                // 8. Bottom Left arc pointing the top left
                arcTo(
                    rect = Rect(
                        offset = Offset(0f, capsuleHeight - cornerShape),
                        size = Size(cornerShape, cornerShape)
                    ),
                    startAngleDegrees = 90f,
                    sweepAngleDegrees = 90f,
                    forceMoveTo = false
                )

                //9. Bottom to top line on right side
                lineTo(0f, cornerShape)

                //Top Right arc
                arcTo(
                    rect = Rect(
                        offset = Offset(0f, 0f),
                        size = Size(cornerShape, cornerShape)
                    ),
                    startAngleDegrees = 180f,
                    sweepAngleDegrees = 90f,
                    forceMoveTo = false
                )
                close()
            }
        )
}
```

```
data class PromptShapeData(
    val xIndent: Float = 0f,
    val height: Float = 0f,
    val width: Float = 32f,
    val cornerRadius: CornerSize = CornerSize(50)
)
```